# IIS Test Server From Existing IIS Server with Joomla

Tags: iis, web, joomla, development-environment

I am in a situation where the current web server is a production environment and there is no development environment. It is running Joomla on an IIS Web Server and is an Intranet site with all of the security, IP restrictions, Certificates, and whatever else required to run an enterprise level Intranet site.

I am wondering what I can do to set up a development environment to work within (preferably using some type of version control).

I have full reign over the IIS server, and I have had a co-worker set up a VM clone of the current system to work with, however the security is making it difficult to work with and set up.

I would like to not use Visual Studio as I don't believe I have a license for it; however I can get it if need be. I would like to stick with Notepad++ if at all possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to literally take the site content out and be able to edit and work without any of the security restrictions of the production environment, there's a couple of ways you could do it. However, it's going to depend on what DB the system is running with.

Joomla, regardless of what web platform it is running on, is coded in PHP, so you don't have to worry about getting visual studio. You can use Notepad++ as normal.

**Option 1 - IIS Clone**

If you can take a SQL backup of the database, you build a from-scratch box with IIS. You'd need to add the PHP drivers to IIS to do this. Go to Microsoft's site for more info:

[PHP for IIS](http://php.iis.net/)

**Option 2 - Apache Port**

You can make an Apache box using WAMP to run, if you're using a Windows machine. PHP is PHP, on any platform, so it should work without modification.

The tricky bit will be the database, depending on your situation. If the database is MySQL, you can import your database backup and be good to go, after changing the config files for the Joomla site.

If the site used MSSQL, it's a little trickier. You'll need to install an MSSQL PHP plugin to get this medthod to work. There's plenty of instructions online on how to do this, it's a case of finding the right one for your implementation.